# Expression Language for currentDocument.isNewNote()

Tags: xpages, el, xpages-ssjs

I would like to use the `NotesXSPDocument` property/ method `currentDocument.isNewNote()` with `Expression Language` but without success.

### SSJS (works fine):

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="cfSSJS" value="#{javascript:currentDocument.isNewNote()}"></xp:text>
```

### EL (no success):

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="cfEL" value="#{currentDocument.newNote}"></xp:text>
```

**Hint:** I am working with a `Domino 8.5.3 FP6` Server environment

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `isNewNote()` is not exposed to EL. Even explicitly referencing the datasource variable explicitly doesn't work.